# dynamic dll method call memory leak

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, dll, memory-leaks

I add dynamic dll to my application. After calling method I have memory leak. Here's my code:

```
static IntfClass GetIClass(string filename)
{
    Assembly classLibrary1 = null;
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int read = 0;
            while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
                ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            classLibrary1 = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    foreach (Type type in classLibrary1.GetExportedTypes())
    {
        if (type.GetInterface("IntfClass") != null)
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IntfClass;
    }
    throw new Exception("no class found that implements interface IntfClass");
}
```

calling:

```
IntfClass class1 = GetIClass("myDllName.dll");
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(class1.runReport));
t.Start((object)report);
```

I added thread, case my application transfers control to dll, after finishing completion of the dll method gives control back.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "memory leak" ? Assembly.Load will load an assembly into your app, which space will not be released (the assembly won't be unloaded) until the app closes.

Comment: After dll method calling I have 100 CPU usage, everything working slow.

Comment: What's the dll method doing then? Can we see that code too?

Comment: dll method works with database and form report using FastReport.dll. Nothing special. But it's really problem in dll or not correctly invoking method from main program?

Answer (score 0):

Create a seperate AppDomain to load your assembly, and try unloading it using AppDomain's Unload method.

Eg:

```
void LoadAssembly(){
AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("CreateNewDomain");
    newDomain.ExecuteAssembly("filename");
    AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);
}
```